# Drupal | Panels+Views: What arguments are needed for one panel to dynamically generate for mulitible-contributing users?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-panels

So I'm designing a Drupal 6 site for a lefty political party. I want to generate 48 separate "Candidate Pages" from a single configuration of Views+Panels. The panel will include picture, bio, blogroll (views), and some social media widgets.

Each candidate URL is formatted /elect[username] (where each candidate is a user, and each username is their firstlast real time).

My question is: how should I best go about configuring this panel (and views)?

I know there are two main options: 1. pull the URL into Panels and Views 2. Associate the author of the content to the Panels and Views arguments.

What do people think is best, and how might I go about defining the necessary arguments?

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the content you would like to feature on the page and the most efficient way to query it.

My first guess would be to override the user page in Panels, this will take care of the picture and basic information.

Considering that the user can be used as argument in Views , retrieving a candidate's content type should be pretty straightforward, whether it's a bio or a blogroll.

Bear in mind that when defining your various content types you can add a user reference field, this could come handy for other types of content...

Finally the Content Profile module could be a good addition.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty well what I did. I overrode the profile content type using Panels. I used user reference and Content Profile and Image Attach to help with the views. I set the contextual filters for the view to look for the node author (I know that's not a great recap, but it's been a long night). I'd like to do a step-by-step, but I don't think I really nailed the 'best practices' enough for that.